# SAP HANA system privilege and application privilege within the granted_privilege table

Tags: hana, elevated-privileges

My question might be pretty simple and i am not sure about the answer. Looking at the attached image from the granted_privileges table within HANA, I needed to know the following:

1. For the object_type = "SYSTEMPRIVILEGE", "APPLICATIONPRIVILEGE" and "ANALYTICALPRIVILEGE" in the screenshot, does it need to be assigned a schema within the "SCHEMA_NAME" column, for the user/grantee to be able to use the privilege? Or are these privileges applicable to the user/grantee even if SCHEMA_NAME column shows "?" ?

2.Similar to 1. does the object_type = "TABLE" and "SCHEMA" need to be assigned to a certain schema for the grantee to be able to perform the functions?

3. Last is the object_type = "REPO" (not listed in the screenshot), in the extract I have, some users and grantees have privilege of "REPO.EDIT_NATIVE_OBJECTS". The privilege is assigned under OBJECT_NAME=".REPO_PACKAGE_ROOT". However, a schema is not assigned within SCHEMA_NAME (it is showing a ?). Does the user/grantee still have this access?

[image: Object table]

Answer (score 1):

The columns in the `GRANTED_PRIVILEGES` view provide information about both the *privileges* as well as *who/what* granted them to *who/what*.

Privileges apply in different situations in SAP HANA. Some apply to working with tables/views/procedures etc. basically *DB objects* that live in a schema and which one could uniquely address by `schema_name.object_name`.  For those privileges you’ll find the columns for `schema_name` and `object_name` contain this information.

For privileges that concern a schema, the `object_name` will not be filled as it does not concern a specific object but the schema instead.

The other privileges are not concerned about these regular DB objects so, again, the columns to identify DB objects are empty.

These columns are **not** concerned with whether or not the privileges have been granted. If a privilege is listed as a row in the view it **is** granted.
Instead, the columns just provide specific information when these information make sense for the specific privilege.